# Is there a way to do snapshot comparisons on ios with physical devices?

Tags: automated-tests, xctest, snapshot

I'm implementing a test automation suit for ios application. Since it developed using metal framework, I cannot run it on simulators. So is there any way to automate snapshot comparisons with real devices?

I'm using XCTest to do automation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no screenshot comparison on real devices framework available, and you need to automate it yourself. Possible steps:

1. You can save you custom screenshot with this snippet

```swift
        let image = XCUIScreen.main.screenshot().image
        let attachment = XCTAttachment(image: image)
        attachment.lifetime = .keepAlways
        attachment.name = "Main Screen"
        add(attachment)
```

2. Such screenshots will be included inside your `.xcresult` file
3. Process those images with tools like `imagemagic`

Comment: For extracting the screenshots out of xcresult, you can use xcparse: https://github.com/ChargePoint/xcparse